# PHP - Passing variable as reference generated unspecified error

Tags: php, reference

I'm getting an error when using a variable reference.  Am I missing something obvious?

basically...

```
$required = array();
$optional = array();

foreach($things as $thing){
  $list =& $thing->required ? $required : $optional;
  $list[] = $thing;
}
```

(looping thru list of things, if the thing's required property is true, pass that thing to the list of required things, other pass it to the list of optional things...)

tyia

Comment: @ultimatebuster - 500 Internal Server Error - nothing else is specified

Comment: You should use your server log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, it seems like you're trying to separate things that are required or optional into different arrays.

```
<?php

foreach ( $things as $thing )
{
  if ( $thing->required )
    $required[] = $thing;
  else
    $optional[] = $thing;
}
```

If you insist on doing it on a single line, you could do this:

```
<?php

foreach ( $things as $thing )
  ${$thing->required ? 'required' : 'optional'}[] = $thing;
```

The problem with your code is `$list =& $thing->required ? $required : $optional;`. PHP is ignoring the `? $required : $optional` part is assigning $this->required to `$list`. When you try to add to the array on the following it, `$list` is a scalar and no longer an array so it's failing. The only way that I can think to solve that problem is to go with one of the solutions above or to create function that return the array by reference.

**Reference**: From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php:

> Please note that the ternary operator
>   is a statement, and that it doesn't
>   evaluate to a variable, but to the
>   result of a statement. This is
>   important to know if you want to
>   return a variable by reference. The
>   statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b;
>   in a return-by-reference function will
>   therefore not work and a warning is
>   issued in later PHP versions.

Comment: yes, that works and is what i'm using while trying to figure out why the reference is failing - any idea why saving the array to a reference fails?

Comment: @Big MoMo - You can't do what you're doing. I'll add it to my answer.